# Lambda for finding differences in properties with reflection not returning correctly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda

I am trying to solve a problem based on a few other post. I am looking at multiple objects in a list that have the same propoerties, and I am needing to verify that they are all the same value in each object. If not, I need to flag that the objects have conflicting property values. The code I am trying and though would work is below, but is always returning true to add the property to the list even if the values are all the same in the list items.

```
public List<string> JobHasConflictingTaxForms(Job job, List<string> propertiesToCheck)
{
    var conflictingPropertiesList = new List<string>();

    foreach(string prop in propertiesToCheck)
    {
         if (!job.TaxForms.TrueForAll(t => t.ARecord.GetType().GetProperty(prop)
                          .GetValue(t.ARecord, null) ==
                           job.TaxForms[0].ARecord.GetType().GetProperty(prop)
                          .GetValue(job.TaxForms[0].ARecord, null)))
         {
             conflictingPropertiesList.Add(prop);
         }
    }

    return conflictingPropertiesList;
}
```

Each tax form has a object as a property called "ARecord". These are the properties that I need to verify are universally the same for every tax form, and if not, then I need to flag there is a difference in one. What am I missing, or doing wrong with this lambda statement? even when I have all the same values, or three forms with the same values, and one form that has one property different, it returns the same results. It always returns true.

P.S.  I have also tried to use Any(i =>    logic != other item).  But wasn't working how I intended it to.

The TaxForm Class

```
 public class TaxForm 
{
    #region Properties

    public string TaxFormType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string FileFullName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ShouldProcess
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Corrected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TRecord TRecord
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ARecord ARecord
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public BRecord BRecord
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<string> BRecords
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasConflictingrecords
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasDataConflict
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
```

}

And now the ARecord Class

```
public class ARecord
{
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Found at POS(12) for 8
    /// </summary>
    public string PayerTIN
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Found at POS(38) for 39.
    /// </summary>
    public string PayerName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Found at POS(134) for 39.
    /// </summary>
    public string PayerAddress
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// found at POS(255) for 14.
    /// </summary>
    public string PayerPhone
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Found at POS(2) for 3.
    /// </summary>
    public string PayerYear
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: What are the property types? Is any them itself a collection?

Comment: No. The only collection are the TaxForms.  Then a object property ARecord. Then regular properties on that are all string types. So the ARecord, is not a collection nor has any collections in it.  I can post a quick example of the two classes.

Comment: I hope it is explained clearly and shown in the code what I am trying to acomplish here. If not, I can give more explanation. Would like to use a reflective method though to handle this in less code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see which particular property returns `false` incorrectly?

Comment: If all of the properties are strings, try using the static `string.Equals` method instead of the == operator.  The == operator may be performing a reference comparison in this case instead of a value comparison.  Not saying it is, but try it with the other method to see if it makes a difference.  Upon looking up the `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method, it returns an `Object`.  The == operator for object does a reference comparison.  You need to cast to a `string` and do a string equality comparison.

Comment: Let me try that out real quick.... Will update

Comment: @Tony Beautiful and genius. I didn't realize it returned object, but thought type would come with it. When I cast each as string and then works perfectly.

Comment: @Casey I would recommend that you search online for a library to do what you are trying to do. The route you have chosen for implementing this method is extremely slow. There should be plenty of examples on the internet which show how to do the same thing by using a cached `Func<T, T, bool>` that is compiled at runtime, which is much more performant. You can choose to write it using pure IL or by Expression trees.

Comment: Yea, there is a performance hit when using reflection, but the amount of data being passed through this will not be large at all. Very minimal. I will still look into it though. Sometimes, I think that libraries are just doing what a user may do, but at your disposal.  But your method you mention I will look into to. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method returns the value of the property it references as type `Object`.  The == operator that is executed is the one for the `Object` class, not the one for `String`.

To have the correct comparison method execute, you need to cast the return value of the call to `PropertyInfo.GetValue` into a `string` and then use either the == operator or call the static `string.Equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

@Tony's advice, they were being compared by an object instance, and not the actuall string value.  The following code corrected the problem, and gave me the correct outcome.

```
foreach(string prop in propertiesToCheck)
        {
             if(!job.TaxForms.TrueForAll(t => t.ARecord.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(t.ARecord, null).ToString().Equals(job.TaxForms[0].ARecord.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(job.TaxForms[0].ARecord, null).ToString())))
             {
                 conflictingPropertiesList.Add(prop);
             }
        }
```

So this should be better?

Comment: This code will break whenever there is a `null` value.

Comment: That is correct. I do check for null entries though, and do not leave the properties null. Couldn't you just use Convert.ToString(null as object)  to get a returned "" value to handle it?   In case anyone is wondering and wanting to use something similiar.

Comment: You should just use `string.Equals` to compare the strings.  Clear, straightforward, and effective.